# Node.js Registration Form

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, registration

I am trying to implement a registration form into my web app. Once I insert the 'name' and 'email' provided by the user into my database (Mysql). I need ***separate*** error messages to pop up on the registration form if the 'name' or 'email' are already in use, something like

> "the 'name' is already in use"

or

> "the 'email' is already in use"

The problem is I use the error I get from the Mysql to show the message

> "the 'name' or 'email' is already in use"

My question is how can i use the Mysql error to distinguish whether it is  the 'name' or the 'email' that is being duplicated.

```
app.post(myArgs[0]+"/register", function(req,res){
      con.query('insert into users values(UUID(),\'' + req.body.user + '\',\''+req.body.pass+'\',\''+req.body.mail+'\',NULL)',function(err,res){
        if(err){
            console.error(err+"  Ooops name or email already in use !"); //here is where I want to find out whether it is the name or the email that is already in use! 
            errorregister();
          return;
        } else {
            passregister();
        }
      })
    function errorregister(){
      res.redirect(myArgs[0]+"/register");
      console.log(_dict);
    }
    function passregister(){
      res.redirect(myArgs[0]+"/login");
      console.log(_dict);
    }
  });
```

Comment: you set name and email as unique key in mysql?

Comment: @PareshGami
Yes, name and email are Unique keys in my database.

Comment: so before inserting please check name or email exist or not

Comment: @PareshGami
I tried that before but couldn't get it to work, how would you do so ?

Comment: Please take a look here might be help you http://keepnote.cc/nodemysqlquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this is how i got it done

```
app.post(myArgs[0]+"/register", function(req,res){
      con.query('insert into users values(UUID(),\'' + req.body.user + '\',\''+req.body.pass+'\',\''+req.body.mail+'\',NULL)',function(err,res){
        if(err){
          error(err);
            return;
        } else {
            passregister();
        }
      })
      function error(err){
        if (err.toString().search("'PRIMARY'") != -1 ){
          console.error("  Ooops!!! name duplicated"); 
          res.redirect(myArgs[0]+"/register")
        } else {
            console.error("  Ooops!!! email duplicated");
            res.redirect(myArgs[0]+"/register")
          }
          return;
      }
    function passregister(){
      _dict[req.body.user]={};
      res.redirect(myArgs[0]+"/login");
      console.log(_dict);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

After the DB give you a error on inserting, you know that either `email`or `name`, or both, is duplicated.

You can then search the DB for `name`, then for `email`.

After that, customizing your error message is easy.

Checking before inserting could go wrong in case of race conditions (two users trying to register the same name/email at the same time). After inserting, you know for sure something is duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Check for error `1586` when inserting in MySQL([List of error codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html))

You can check for which `INSERT` the error occurred.

Whenever a duplicate key is being inserted in a UNIQUE KEY column, this error is returned. Based on this error you can send a `AJAX response` to client, which would update `DOM` to show the required error.